# How to configure settings.xml in maven to download jars from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Tags: maven, repository, settings

How to configure settings.xml in maven to download the jars from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 instead http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Comment: It looks you are using an old Maven versions which means before Maven 3.2.3. In Maven 3.2.3 this has been changed to be the default using https:...So best is to update Maven version to newest version 3.3.9...

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise